# What am I doing wrong with my Dom4j Code?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

Hey guys I am working on a load class for my project that loads and pulls a info from a xml files. I have been following a few guides online but I am running into the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException. I know the code is finding the save file because I can print out the name. But when I try to pull out the info I get that error. Snippet of code is below if there is no error in there let me know and Ill post more.

```
public void LoadProjects()
    {
        try
        {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("D:/workspace/Project Program/Projects/")).forEach(filePath ->
            {
                if(Files.isRegularFile(filePath))
                {
                    System.out.println("Testing");
                    try 
                    {
                        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
                        Document document = reader.read(filePath.toFile());
                        System.out.println(document.getName());
                        Node node = document.selectSingleNode("///Project/Info");
                        //String name = node.valueOf("@Name");
                        //String projNum = node.valueOf("@ProjectNumber");
                        //node = document.selectSingleNode("//Project/Dates");
                        //String dueBy = node.valueOf("@DueBy");
                        //CButton temp = new CButton(name, projNum, dueBy);
                        //Console.console.AddToList(temp);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the [jaxen jar](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/releases.html) to your servers lib?

Your code seems correct so far but please add as much information as possible from the beginning.

Ff you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have not. I added the Dom4j. Let me try adding that one in real quick. Also edited to add the rest of the file

Comment: Did you add it to your classpath?

Comment: I am sorry SWiggels I am not sure what you mean by Maven or the xml you posted below it.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace please? 

The xml/maven was just in Case you are using maven, if you don't just leave it.

Comment: I just figured it out. It was a jaxen jar i needed I guess the first one I tried wasn't up to date. Thanks for the help man. :)